How to send an image as binary string in Flutter using Http package?
I have to send a png/jpg image to the server in the binary string form. It is also specified in the Swagger that content-type of the request has to be "multipart/form-data".

I select images using ImagePicker package and then convert the image to base64Encoded string:
var photoAsBytes = await profilePhoto.readAsBytes();
List<int> photoAsIntList = photoAsBytes.toList();
String base64EncodedPhoto = base64Encode(photoAsIntList);

RequestResult? reqResult = await UserApiRequest.addUserPhoto(
  base64EncodedPhoto
);

After that I'm sending http request:
String apiBaseUrl = SecretService.instance.apiBaseUrl;
Uri requestPath = Uri.parse("$apiBaseUrl$requestUrl");

var request = MultipartRequest("POST", requestPath);
request.headers.addAll(requestHeaders);

var imageFile = MultipartFile.fromString(
  "file",
  requestBody as String,
  contentType: MediaType("multipart", "form-data")
);
request.files.add(imageFile);

Response response = await Response.fromStream(await request.send());
print("Result: ${response.statusCode}");

I should get a path for the image as the response from server but I get "InvalidFile" error in the service response. What am I doing wrong?

I think you need to check with your backend developers what they receive and why they return that error. What Http status code do you get as response?

It is confusing but I think contentType is supposed to be the mime-type of the file. Not the content-type of the request body. Also my guess is that the field name is image not file. The second argument should be the file bytes profilePhoto.readAsBytes()

I'm getting a status code of 400. It is a case study I'm working on so I can't do anything about backend

I suspect this issue is that you are base64 encoding the raw file data. Here is an implementation I did for MultipartForm data:
FormData getFileFormData(String key, List<PlatformFile> files) {
  final fileMap = files.map((file) => MapEntry(
      key,
      MultipartFile(
          kIsWeb
              ? file.readStream!
              : file.path != null
                  ? File(file.path!).readAsBytes().asStream()
                  : Stream.fromIterable([file.bytes!.toList()]),
          file.size,
          filename: file.name)));
  final formData = FormData();
  formData.files.addAll(fileMap);
  return formData;
}

This implementation tries to account for differences in the data received from a file picker on web and mobile. I think this line:
File(file.path!).readAsBytes().asStream()

is what you need. You need to convert the file bytes to a stream.

Unfortunately this solution did not work either

Well, I am using dio and you are using the built-in http library. My solution will not map one-to-one. I took this code straight from a utility file that I use. You may want to use MultipartFile.fromBytes since you are getting a file object from the image picker package. profilePhoto.readAsBytes() would be the second argument to MultipartFile.fromBytes. MultipartFile.fromBytes("image", profilePhoto.readAsBytes(), ...)
